# Avoid overlapping of lists in UL LI

Tags: html, css, overlapping

On the following code I do NOT want the 'level 2' list items be overlapped. How can I achieve that. Here is my sample code.

```
    <style type="text/css">
.tree-ul
{
    background:none;
    margin:0px 0px 0px -70px;
    padding:0;
    clear:both;

}
.tree-ul li {
clear:both;float: left;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
height:100px;
width:100px;
border:solid #099 solid 1px;
background:#CCC;
list-style:none;
margin:5px 5px 0px 70px;

}
</style>
        <ul class="tree-ul">
            <li>Level 0



                <ul>
                    <li>Level 1



                        <ul>
                            <li>a Level 2</li>
                            <li>a Level 2</li>
                            <li>a Level 2</li>
                            <li>a Level 2</li>
                            <li>a Level 2</li>
                            <li>a Level 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Level 1</li>
                    <li>Level 1



                        <ul>
                            <li>b Level 2</li>
                            <li>b Level 2</li>
                            <li>b Level 2</li>
                            <li>b Level 2</li>
                            <li>b Level 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Level 1</li>
                    <li>Level 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The idea is to show the boxes vertically without being overlapped.
Thanks in advance.